# How to apply setColorFilter() with animation?

Tags: android, android-view, objectanimator, colorfilter

I have a view, which I want to transform into red color with an animation.

I tried to apply a color filter from 00 alpha color to FF alpha color, but when the animation starts, obviously the image it's transparent for the 00 alpha color filter, so this is not the solution:

```
    ValueAnimator anim = new ValueAnimator();
    anim.setIntValues(Color.parseColor("#00EE1B1B"), Color.parseColor("#FFEE1B1B"));
    anim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            view.setColorFilter((Integer)valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue(), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        }
    });

    anim.setDuration(4000);
    anim.start();
```

How can I animate a color filter from none to red?

Answer (score 1):

Well finally I discovered that white color filter doesn't modify the view... so simply doing this, the problem is solved:

```
finalEnemyWeaponColorFilter.setIntValues(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), Color.parseColor("#EE1B1B"));
```